# Как назначить int и str на одну переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать чтобы программа одновременно понимала входящие str и int на переменной b? При попытке ввести "Выход" - `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Выход'`

```
from random import randint

a = randint(0, 101)

while True:
    b = int(input('Угадай число или набери "Выход": '))
    if b == 'Выход':
        print("Выход из программы!")
        break
    elif b > 100:
        print('От 1 до 100!')
    elif b == a:
        print("Угадал!")
    elif a > b:
        print('Мало!')
    elif a < b:
        print('Много!')
```

Comment: Никак, значение переменной одновременно может иметь только какой-то один тип. Но что мешает вам сделать `b = int(b)` уже после проверки на выход?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала сравнить со строкой, потом преобразовать к целочисленному типу, и работать как с числом.

```
from random import randint

a = randint(0, 101)

while True:
    answer = int(input('Угадай число или набери "Выход": '))
    if answer == 'Выход':
        print("Выход из программы!")
        break

    b = int(answer)
    if not (1 <= b <= 100):
        print('От 1 до 100!')
    elif b == a:
        print("Угадал!")
        break
    elif a > b:
        print('Мало!')
    elif a < b:
        print('Много!')
```

Answer (score -1):

Нельзя такое сделать. Можно сделать перед сравнением с числом превращение в число. То есть:

```
a = input()
if a == 'Выход':
    pass
elif int(a) == 0:
    pass
```

Comment: Странный у вас код, проверку на тип строка можно сделать так: `isinstance(a, str)`

Comment: 'str' это пример строки. Уже исправил.